# Jaxb dont discovery correct son of my base class

Tags: java, xml, inheritance, jaxb

In a personal project i have the following xml structures to make my own java classes:

first:

```
<response>
<action>getcredits</action>
<data>
    <account>
        <username>aptalaser</username>
        <balance>193</balance>
    </account>
</data>
```

second:

```
<response>
<action>getMsgInfoByID</action>
<data>
    <messageid>c36d7ee5-16f9-4193-9a75-0537e590e9d3</messageid>
    <originator>+17036231081 [4]</originator>
    <recipient>10958</recipient>
    <folder>INBOX</folder>
    <senttime>2011.10.17 13:10:26</senttime>
    <receivedtime>2011.10.17 13:10:26</receivedtime>
    <creationtime>2011.10.17 13:10:26</creationtime>
    <callbackid/>
    <state>0</state>
    <operatornames>
        <operatorname>SMPP0</operatorname>
    </operatornames>
    <routes>
        <route>defin_admin</route>
    </routes>
    <optionalfields>
        <optionalfield name="30" value="35333131572D31303133322D303530364E2D333434544600"/>
        <optionalfield name="8528" value="017F"/>
    </optionalfields>
    <messagetype>SMS:TEXT</messagetype>
    <messagedata>Test message</messagedata>
</data>
```

third:

```
<response>
<action>sendmessage</action>
<data>
    <acceptreport>
        <statuscode>0</statuscode>
        <statusmessage>Message accepted for delivery</statusmessage>
        <messageid>0f06bbd9-0894-4fb4-9c4b-68e29363d299</messageid>
        <originator>aptalaser</originator>
        <recipient>8588430260</recipient>
        <messagetype>SMS:TEXT</messagetype>
        <messagedata>Bom dia cara.</messagedata>
    </acceptreport>
</data>
```

The structures are divided in two places: a action to indicating the method acessed and the data section: a generic portion with will change the content dinamically in response to access a different method.
Following this idea i decide create a Response class with two field: a String action and a field Data:

The Response class:

```
/* omite desnecessary imports */

@XmlRootElement(name = "response")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Response {

private String action;

private Data data;

public String getAction() {
    return action;
}

/* omitted set methds */

@XmlElementRef
public Data getData() {
    return data;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String template = "( action: %s, data: %s )";
    return String.format(template, this.action, this.data);
}
}
```

The Data class, the base class for all Data sections

```
@XmlSeeAlso({ GetInfoMessageData.class, GetAccountData.class, SendMessageData.class })
public class Data {

    }
```

The GetAccountClass to represent account retrieve information

```
/* omite desnecessary imports */

@XmlRootElement(name = "data")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class GetAccountData extends Data {

private List<Account> account;

public List<Account> getAccount() {
    return account;
}

/* omitted set methos */

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Account( %s )", this.account);
}

public static class Account {
    private String username;

    private Long balance;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public Long getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    /* omitted set methods */

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("[ usr: %s, credit: %d ]", this.username, this.balance);
    }
}
}
```

The class represents the message data

```
/* omite desnecessary imports */

@XmlRootElement(name = "data")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class GetInfoMessageData extends Data {

private String messageId;

private String destino;

private String recipiente;

private String folder;

private Date dataCricao;

private Date dataEnvio;

private Date dataRecebimento;

private Integer status;

private String tipoMensagem;

private String mensagem;

private List<Protocolo> protocolos;

private List<Route> rotas;

private List<Field> optionalFields;

private Error error;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public static class Protocolo {
    private String nomeProtocolo;

    @XmlElement(name = "operatorname", defaultValue = "")
    public String getNomeProtocolo() {
        return nomeProtocolo;
    }

    /* omitted set methods */
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public static class Error {
    private String errorMessage;

    @XmlElement(name = "errormessage")
    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    /* omitted set methods */
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public static class Route {
    private String route;

    @XmlElement(defaultValue = "")
    public String getRoute() {
        return route;
    }

    /* omitted set methods */
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public static class Field {
    private String name;

    private String value;

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }


    /* omitted set methods */
}

@XmlElement(name = "messageid", required = true)
public final String getMessageId() {
    return messageId;
}

@XmlElement(name = "originator", required = true)
public final String getDestino() {
    return destino;
}

@XmlElement(name = "recipient", defaultValue = "")
public final String getRecipiente() {
    return recipiente;
}

@XmlElement(name = "folder", defaultValue = "")
public final String getFolder() {
    return folder;
}

@XmlElement(name = "creationtime")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type = Date.class, value = JavaDateAdapter.class)
public final Date getDataCricao() {
    return dataCricao;
}

@XmlElement(name = "senttime")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type = Date.class, value = JavaDateAdapter.class)
public final Date getDataEnvio() {
    return dataEnvio;
}

@XmlElement(name = "receivedtime")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type = Date.class, value = JavaDateAdapter.class)
public final Date getDataRecebimento() {
    return dataRecebimento;
}

@XmlElement(name = "state", required = true)
public final Integer getStatus() {
    return status;
}

@XmlElement(name = "messagetype", required = true)
public final String getTipoMensagem() {
    return tipoMensagem;
}

@XmlElement(name = "messagedata")
public final String getMensagem() {
    return mensagem;
}

@XmlElement(name = "operatornames")
public final List<Protocolo> getProtocolos() {
    return protocolos;
}

@XmlElement(name = "routes")
public final List<Route> getRotas() {
    return rotas;
}

@XmlElement(name = "optionalfield")
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "optionalfields")
public List<Field> getOptionalFields() {
    return optionalFields;
}

@XmlElement(name = "error")
public Error getError() {
    return error;
}
 /* omitted set methods */
```

}

The class represent the sendMessage response operation

```
/* omite desnecessary imports */

@XmlRootElement(name = "data")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class SendMessageData extends Data {

private AcceptReport acceptReport;

@XmlElement(name = "acceptreport")
public AcceptReport getAcceptReport() {
    return acceptReport;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public void setAcceptReport(AcceptReport acceptReport) {
    this.acceptReport = acceptReport;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Report( %s )", this.acceptReport);
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "acceptreport")
public static class AcceptReport {
    private Integer status;

    private String statusMessage;

    private String messageId;

    private String originator;

    private String recipient;

    private String messageType;

    private String messageData;

    @XmlElement(name = "statuscode")
    public Integer getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "statusmessage")
    public String getStatusMessage() {
        return statusMessage;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "messageid")
    public String getMessageId() {
        return messageId;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "originator")
    public String getOriginator() {
        return originator;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "recipient")
    public String getRecipient() {
        return recipient;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "messagetype")
    public String getMessageType() {
        return messageType;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "messagedata")
    public String getMessageData() {
        return messageData;
    }

    /* set methods omited */

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("[ stats: %d, msgId: %s, msg: %s ]", this.status, this.messageId, this.messageData);
    }
}
}
```

The xml 'data' section don't have anything to identifing 'what son of Data will be use in the ummarshaling operation?'
My test works fine in the marshalling operation but in the ummarshalling its broken because the jaxb don't identify the son of Data to use.

```
/* omite desnecessary imports */

public class Teste {

public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(
            Data.class, GetAccountData.class, 
            GetInfoMessageData.class, Response.class, SendMessageData.class
        );

        Marshaller marshaller = ctx.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        Response r = new Response();
        r.setAction("getcredits");

        GetAccountData data = new GetAccountData();
        Account account = new GetAccountData.Account();

        account.setUsername("aptalaser");
        account.setBalance(12523L);

        data.setAccount(Arrays.asList(account));
        r.setData(data);

        //in there is equal to first xml
        marshaller.marshal(r, System.out);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = ctx.createUnmarshaller();

        Response resp = (Response) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("./get-credits.xml"));

        //but in there the resp retrieved is to the third xml(and the Data field is null)
        System.out.println(resp);
}
}
```

The question is: I need implement my own customized converter or i can make that with simple configurations like annotations?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you post the XML that's generated when you marshal to system.out? The data field should have an attribute telling you what the child type was.

Comment: For information on JAXB and inheritance check out:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html

Comment: in the previous sample the marshalling process results in the following xml:

`code`
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <response>
        <action>getcredits</action>
        <data>
            <account>
                <balance>12523</balance>
                <username>aptalaser</username>
            </account>
        </data>
    </response>
`code`

Answer (score 0):

For the purposes of unmarshalling you need to have a unique identifier that can be used to identify the appropriate subclass to instantiate.

### `@XmlElementRef`

Since you are using `@XmlElementRef` this unique identifier should be the `@XmlRootElement` of the subclass, but you currently have all subclasses with `@XmlRootElement(name="data")`.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html

### `xsi:type` Attribute

If you want to always leverage the `data` element then you need something else as the inheritance indicator.  If you remove the `@XmlElementRef` annotation then JAXB will leverage the `xsi:type` attribute for this purpose.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html

### Element Content

If neither of the above will work for you then you can leverage an `XmlAdapter`.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/01/jaxb-and-inhertiance-using-xmladapter.html

---

### UPDATE

> Thank you @Blaise this help me so much, one more thing: i need process
>   this model, so i need implement different response class with
>   appropriate subclass field?

If you know which type of response you are receiving this is a valid approach.  Then when you do the `unmarshal` you can specify the class you are unmarshalling.  You will need to do this because the `response` root element corresponds to all the response classes you will make.

```
GetAccountDataResponse = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml, GetAccountDataResponse.class).getValue();
```

If you don't know what type of response you are receiving and need to decide based on the content of the message then an `XmlAdapter` approach for handling inheritance will work.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/01/jaxb-and-inhertiance-using-xmladapter.html

Comment: Thank you @Blaise this help me so much, 

one more thing: i need process this model, so i need implement different response class with appropriate subclass field?

Comment: @SamuelMedeiros - I have updated my answer to address this comment.

Comment: Thank you @Blaise again this help so much i will try use XmlAdapter.